# mdadm array assemble causes kernel hang

Tags: linux, centos, raid, mdadm

I have a 2 large mdadm arrays, and I combine them in a volume group. 
I was recently adding new drives to the second array and I suffered a power outage.  Typically, I don't have major problems getting arrays to restart or resume a reshape after an outage, but this time I am having a lot of trouble.

System details: CentOS 6.8 x64

```
Linux myserver 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 23 19:58:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I first boot up, the array assembles but doesn't start because it is degraded.  I can't get it started with:

```
mdadm -R /dev/md126
```

I then stop it:

```
mdadm -S /dev/md126
```

If I assemble it normally, it won't start:

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: device 26 in /dev/md/128 has wrong state in superblock, but /dev/sdn seems ok
mdadm: /dev/md/128 assembled from 12 drives and 2 spares - not enough to start the array while not clean - consider --force.
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

so I assemble with:

```
mdadm --assemble --scan --force
mdadm: clearing FAULTY flag for device 1 in /dev/md/128 for /dev/sdn
mdadm: Marking array /dev/md/128 as 'clean'
mdadm: /dev/md/128 has been started with 12 drives (out of 13) and 2 spares.
```

At this point, my session is hung.  But if I ssh back into the device I can run commands while the other session continues to hang.

cat /proc/mdstat

```
md128 : active raid6 sdf[0] sdl[9](S) sdn[14](S) sdo[6] sdm[7] sdc[10] sdb[11] sdd[12] sde[13] sdk[5] sdj[4] sdi[3] sdh[2] sdg[1]
      23441323008 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [13/12] [UUUUUUUUUUUU_]
      [>....................]  reshape =  0.0% (128496/3906887168) finish=133658963.6min speed=0K/sec
      bitmap: 1/30 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdaa[2] sdab[13] sdac[0] sdad[15] sdy[4] sdx[5] sdz[14] sdw[6] sdr[9] sds[8] sdq[10] sdp[16] sdu[11] sdv[7] sdt[12]
      50789533184 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [15/15] [UUUUUUUUUUUUUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

The reshape never makes it past that point. It's always stuck there.

In the dmesg I then get the following error

```
created bitmap (30 pages) for device md128
md128: bitmap initialized from disk: read 2 pages, set 1 of 59615 bits
md128: detected capacity change from 0 to 24003914760192
md: reshape of RAID array md128
md: minimum _guaranteed_  speed: 1000 KB/sec/disk.
md: using maximum available idle IO bandwidth (but not more than 200000 KB/sec) for reshape.
 md128:
md: using 128k window, over a total of 3906887168k.
 unknown partition table
INFO: task mdadm:2357 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Not tainted 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
mdadm         D 0000000000000002     0  2357   2179 0x00000004
 ffff880821773688 0000000000000082 0000000000000000 0000000000000086
 ffff880821773618 ffffffff810633a3 0000013e9de36948 ffff88081f96d440
 ffff88081dc65ed0 000000010010516a ffff88081d713068 ffff880821773fd8
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff810633a3>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
 [<ffffffffa0240805>] get_active_stripe+0x2d5/0x880 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff81130d00>] ? mempool_alloc+0x20/0x140
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff810a6bce>] ? prepare_to_wait+0x4e/0x80
 [<ffffffffa02455ef>] make_request+0x19f/0xcb0 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff812ab7de>] ? __sg_alloc_table+0x7e/0x130
 [<ffffffff81056cc5>] ? gup_pte_range+0xe5/0x130
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff8143066f>] md_make_request+0xdf/0x240
 [<ffffffff8127ddb0>] generic_make_request+0x240/0x5a0
 [<ffffffff811d941c>] ? do_direct_IO+0x57c/0xfa0
 [<ffffffff811d60cb>] ? bio_alloc_bioset+0x5b/0xf0
 [<ffffffff8127e180>] submit_bio+0x70/0x120
 [<ffffffff811daabd>] __blockdev_direct_IO_newtrunc+0xc7d/0x1270
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff811db127>] __blockdev_direct_IO+0x77/0xe0
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff811d73a7>] blkdev_direct_IO+0x57/0x60
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff8113028b>] generic_file_aio_read+0x6bb/0x700
 [<ffffffff8143877f>] ? md_ioctl+0x31f/0x1ac0
 [<ffffffff811d7f00>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
 [<ffffffff81196d47>] ? __dentry_open+0x257/0x380
 [<ffffffff811d6891>] blkdev_aio_read+0x51/0x80
 [<ffffffff81199a6a>] do_sync_read+0xfa/0x140
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff811d66bc>] ? block_ioctl+0x3c/0x40
 [<ffffffff811af522>] ? vfs_ioctl+0x22/0xa0
 [<ffffffff811af6c4>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x84/0x580
 [<ffffffff8123aa06>] ? security_file_permission+0x16/0x20
 [<ffffffff8119a365>] vfs_read+0xb5/0x1a0
 [<ffffffff8119b116>] ? fget_light_pos+0x16/0x50
 [<ffffffff8119a6b1>] sys_read+0x51/0xb0
 [<ffffffff8100b0d2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
INFO: task md128_reshape:2428 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Not tainted 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
md128_reshape D 0000000000000001     0  2428      2 0x00000000
 ffff88081fdcfa60 0000000000000046 0000000000000000 0000000000000086
 ffff88081fdcf9f0 ffffffff810633a3 0000013d983220e0 ffff88081f96d440
 ffff88081dc65ed0 0000000100103f9f ffff88081ea1e5f8 ffff88081fdcffd8
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff810633a3>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
 [<ffffffffa0240805>] get_active_stripe+0x2d5/0x880 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffffa02447c0>] reshape_request+0x440/0xa20 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff810633a3>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
 [<ffffffffa02450b2>] sync_request+0x312/0x3a0 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff81430ff7>] md_do_sync+0x6c7/0xd60
 [<ffffffff81431ae5>] md_thread+0x115/0x150
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff814319d0>] ? md_thread+0x0/0x150
 [<ffffffff810a640e>] kthread+0x9e/0xc0
 [<ffffffff8100c28a>] child_rip+0xa/0x20
 [<ffffffff810a6370>] ? kthread+0x0/0xc0
 [<ffffffff8100c280>] ? child_rip+0x0/0x20
INFO: task blkid:2430 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Not tainted 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
blkid         D 0000000000000002     0  2430      1 0x00000000
 ffff8808211d36f8 0000000000000082 0000000000000000 0000000000000082
 ffff8808211d3688 ffffffff810633a3 0000013d9831af63 ffff88081f96d440
 ffff88081dc65ed0 0000000100104045 ffff88081e615ad8 ffff8808211d3fd8
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff810633a3>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
 [<ffffffffa0240805>] get_active_stripe+0x2d5/0x880 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff8142af00>] ? try_module_get+0x30/0xb0
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff810a6bce>] ? prepare_to_wait+0x4e/0x80
 [<ffffffffa02455ef>] make_request+0x19f/0xcb0 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff81340b4b>] ? mix_pool_bytes_extract+0x16b/0x180
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff81151319>] ? zone_statistics+0x99/0xc0
 [<ffffffff8143066f>] md_make_request+0xdf/0x240
 [<ffffffff8127ddb0>] generic_make_request+0x240/0x5a0
 [<ffffffff81130ba5>] ? mempool_alloc_slab+0x15/0x20
 [<ffffffff81130d43>] ? mempool_alloc+0x63/0x140
 [<ffffffff8127e180>] submit_bio+0x70/0x120
 [<ffffffff811cfc8d>] submit_bh+0x11d/0x1f0
 [<ffffffff811d2a9c>] block_read_full_page+0x27c/0x3a0
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff811513ee>] ? __inc_zone_page_state+0x2e/0x30
 [<ffffffff81145480>] ? __lru_cache_add+0x40/0x90
 [<ffffffff811d7498>] blkdev_readpage+0x18/0x20
 [<ffffffff811441aa>] __do_page_cache_readahead+0x20a/0x210
 [<ffffffff81144251>] force_page_cache_readahead+0x71/0xa0
 [<ffffffff81144773>] page_cache_sync_readahead+0x43/0x50
 [<ffffffff81130128>] generic_file_aio_read+0x558/0x700
 [<ffffffff811d6891>] blkdev_aio_read+0x51/0x80
 [<ffffffff81199a6a>] do_sync_read+0xfa/0x140
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff8115f3d0>] ? unmap_region+0x110/0x130
 [<ffffffff8123aa06>] ? security_file_permission+0x16/0x20
 [<ffffffff8119a365>] vfs_read+0xb5/0x1a0
 [<ffffffff8119b116>] ? fget_light_pos+0x16/0x50
 [<ffffffff8119a6b1>] sys_read+0x51/0xb0
 [<ffffffff8100b0d2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
INFO: task mdadm:2357 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Not tainted 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
mdadm         D 0000000000000002     0  2357   2179 0x00000004
 ffff880821773688 0000000000000082 0000000000000000 0000000000000086
 ffff880821773618 ffffffff810633a3 0000013e9de36948 ffff88081f96d440
 ffff88081dc65ed0 000000010010516a ffff88081d713068 ffff880821773fd8
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff810633a3>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
 [<ffffffffa0240805>] get_active_stripe+0x2d5/0x880 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff81130d00>] ? mempool_alloc+0x20/0x140
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff810a6bce>] ? prepare_to_wait+0x4e/0x80
 [<ffffffffa02455ef>] make_request+0x19f/0xcb0 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff812ab7de>] ? __sg_alloc_table+0x7e/0x130
 [<ffffffff81056cc5>] ? gup_pte_range+0xe5/0x130
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff8143066f>] md_make_request+0xdf/0x240
 [<ffffffff8127ddb0>] generic_make_request+0x240/0x5a0
 [<ffffffff811d941c>] ? do_direct_IO+0x57c/0xfa0
 [<ffffffff811d60cb>] ? bio_alloc_bioset+0x5b/0xf0
 [<ffffffff8127e180>] submit_bio+0x70/0x120
 [<ffffffff811daabd>] __blockdev_direct_IO_newtrunc+0xc7d/0x1270
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff811db127>] __blockdev_direct_IO+0x77/0xe0
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff811d73a7>] blkdev_direct_IO+0x57/0x60
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff8113028b>] generic_file_aio_read+0x6bb/0x700
 [<ffffffff8143877f>] ? md_ioctl+0x31f/0x1ac0
 [<ffffffff811d7f00>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
 [<ffffffff81196d47>] ? __dentry_open+0x257/0x380
 [<ffffffff811d6891>] blkdev_aio_read+0x51/0x80
 [<ffffffff81199a6a>] do_sync_read+0xfa/0x140
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff811d66bc>] ? block_ioctl+0x3c/0x40
 [<ffffffff811af522>] ? vfs_ioctl+0x22/0xa0
 [<ffffffff811af6c4>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x84/0x580
 [<ffffffff8123aa06>] ? security_file_permission+0x16/0x20
 [<ffffffff8119a365>] vfs_read+0xb5/0x1a0
 [<ffffffff8119b116>] ? fget_light_pos+0x16/0x50
 [<ffffffff8119a6b1>] sys_read+0x51/0xb0
 [<ffffffff8100b0d2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
INFO: task md128_reshape:2428 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Not tainted 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
md128_reshape D 0000000000000001     0  2428      2 0x00000000
 ffff88081fdcfa60 0000000000000046 0000000000000000 0000000000000086
 ffff88081fdcf9f0 ffffffff810633a3 0000013d983220e0 ffff88081f96d440
 ffff88081dc65ed0 0000000100103f9f ffff88081ea1e5f8 ffff88081fdcffd8
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff810633a3>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
 [<ffffffffa0240805>] get_active_stripe+0x2d5/0x880 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffffa02447c0>] reshape_request+0x440/0xa20 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff810633a3>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
 [<ffffffffa02450b2>] sync_request+0x312/0x3a0 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff81430ff7>] md_do_sync+0x6c7/0xd60
 [<ffffffff81431ae5>] md_thread+0x115/0x150
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff814319d0>] ? md_thread+0x0/0x150
 [<ffffffff810a640e>] kthread+0x9e/0xc0
 [<ffffffff8100c28a>] child_rip+0xa/0x20
 [<ffffffff810a6370>] ? kthread+0x0/0xc0
 [<ffffffff8100c280>] ? child_rip+0x0/0x20
INFO: task blkid:2430 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Not tainted 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
blkid         D 0000000000000002     0  2430      1 0x00000000
 ffff8808211d36f8 0000000000000082 0000000000000000 0000000000000082
 ffff8808211d3688 ffffffff810633a3 0000013d9831af63 ffff88081f96d440
 ffff88081dc65ed0 0000000100104045 ffff88081e615ad8 ffff8808211d3fd8
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff810633a3>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
 [<ffffffffa0240805>] get_active_stripe+0x2d5/0x880 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff8142af00>] ? try_module_get+0x30/0xb0
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff810a6bce>] ? prepare_to_wait+0x4e/0x80
 [<ffffffffa02455ef>] make_request+0x19f/0xcb0 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff81340b4b>] ? mix_pool_bytes_extract+0x16b/0x180
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff81151319>] ? zone_statistics+0x99/0xc0
 [<ffffffff8143066f>] md_make_request+0xdf/0x240
 [<ffffffff8127ddb0>] generic_make_request+0x240/0x5a0
 [<ffffffff81130ba5>] ? mempool_alloc_slab+0x15/0x20
 [<ffffffff81130d43>] ? mempool_alloc+0x63/0x140
 [<ffffffff8127e180>] submit_bio+0x70/0x120
 [<ffffffff811cfc8d>] submit_bh+0x11d/0x1f0
 [<ffffffff811d2a9c>] block_read_full_page+0x27c/0x3a0
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff811513ee>] ? __inc_zone_page_state+0x2e/0x30
 [<ffffffff81145480>] ? __lru_cache_add+0x40/0x90
 [<ffffffff811d7498>] blkdev_readpage+0x18/0x20
 [<ffffffff811441aa>] __do_page_cache_readahead+0x20a/0x210
 [<ffffffff81144251>] force_page_cache_readahead+0x71/0xa0
 [<ffffffff81144773>] page_cache_sync_readahead+0x43/0x50
 [<ffffffff81130128>] generic_file_aio_read+0x558/0x700
 [<ffffffff811d6891>] blkdev_aio_read+0x51/0x80
 [<ffffffff81199a6a>] do_sync_read+0xfa/0x140
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff8115f3d0>] ? unmap_region+0x110/0x130
 [<ffffffff8123aa06>] ? security_file_permission+0x16/0x20
 [<ffffffff8119a365>] vfs_read+0xb5/0x1a0
 [<ffffffff8119b116>] ? fget_light_pos+0x16/0x50
 [<ffffffff8119a6b1>] sys_read+0x51/0xb0
 [<ffffffff8100b0d2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
INFO: task mdadm:2481 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Not tainted 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
mdadm         D 0000000000000003     0  2481   2459 0x00000004
 ffff8808226ef688 0000000000000086 0000000000000000 0000000000000086
 ffff8808226ef618 ffffffff810633a3 0000014fb75098d5 ffff88081f96d440
 ffff88081dc65ed0 0000000100117098 ffff88081e7f7068 ffff8808226effd8
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff810633a3>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
 [<ffffffffa0240805>] get_active_stripe+0x2d5/0x880 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff810a6bce>] ? prepare_to_wait+0x4e/0x80
 [<ffffffffa02455ef>] make_request+0x19f/0xcb0 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff8117ec7c>] ? transfer_objects+0x5c/0x80
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff8117f66e>] ? cache_alloc_refill+0x9e/0x240
 [<ffffffff8143066f>] md_make_request+0xdf/0x240
 [<ffffffff8127ddb0>] generic_make_request+0x240/0x5a0
 [<ffffffff811d941c>] ? do_direct_IO+0x57c/0xfa0
 [<ffffffff81151319>] ? zone_statistics+0x99/0xc0
 [<ffffffff811d60cb>] ? bio_alloc_bioset+0x5b/0xf0
 [<ffffffff8127e180>] submit_bio+0x70/0x120
 [<ffffffff811daabd>] __blockdev_direct_IO_newtrunc+0xc7d/0x1270
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff811db127>] __blockdev_direct_IO+0x77/0xe0
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff811d73a7>] blkdev_direct_IO+0x57/0x60
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff8113028b>] generic_file_aio_read+0x6bb/0x700
 [<ffffffff8143877f>] ? md_ioctl+0x31f/0x1ac0
 [<ffffffff811d7f00>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
 [<ffffffff81196d47>] ? __dentry_open+0x257/0x380
 [<ffffffff811d6891>] blkdev_aio_read+0x51/0x80
 [<ffffffff81199a6a>] do_sync_read+0xfa/0x140
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff811d66bc>] ? block_ioctl+0x3c/0x40
 [<ffffffff811af522>] ? vfs_ioctl+0x22/0xa0
 [<ffffffff811af6c4>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x84/0x580
 [<ffffffff8123aa06>] ? security_file_permission+0x16/0x20
 [<ffffffff8119a365>] vfs_read+0xb5/0x1a0
 [<ffffffff8119b116>] ? fget_light_pos+0x16/0x50
 [<ffffffff8119a6b1>] sys_read+0x51/0xb0
 [<ffffffff8100b0d2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
INFO: task pvscan:2518 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Not tainted 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
pvscan        D 0000000000000003     0  2518   2505 0x00000000
 ffff8808205e3688 0000000000000086 0000000000000000 0000000000000086
 ffff8808205e3618 ffffffff810633a3 000001550b5d4884 ffff88081f96d440
 ffff88081dc65ed0 000000010011ca13 ffff88081ddf5ad8 ffff8808205e3fd8
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff810633a3>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
 [<ffffffffa0240805>] get_active_stripe+0x2d5/0x880 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff810a6bce>] ? prepare_to_wait+0x4e/0x80
 [<ffffffffa02455ef>] make_request+0x19f/0xcb0 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff812ab7de>] ? __sg_alloc_table+0x7e/0x130
 [<ffffffff81056cc5>] ? gup_pte_range+0xe5/0x130
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff8143066f>] md_make_request+0xdf/0x240
 [<ffffffff8127ddb0>] generic_make_request+0x240/0x5a0
 [<ffffffff811d941c>] ? do_direct_IO+0x57c/0xfa0
 [<ffffffff811d60cb>] ? bio_alloc_bioset+0x5b/0xf0
 [<ffffffff8127e180>] submit_bio+0x70/0x120
 [<ffffffff811daabd>] __blockdev_direct_IO_newtrunc+0xc7d/0x1270
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff811db127>] __blockdev_direct_IO+0x77/0xe0
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff811d73a7>] blkdev_direct_IO+0x57/0x60
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff8113028b>] generic_file_aio_read+0x6bb/0x700
 [<ffffffff811d7ef0>] ? blkdev_get+0x10/0x20
 [<ffffffff811d7f00>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
 [<ffffffff81196d47>] ? __dentry_open+0x257/0x380
 [<ffffffff811d6891>] blkdev_aio_read+0x51/0x80
 [<ffffffff81199a6a>] do_sync_read+0xfa/0x140
 [<ffffffff81397a3f>] ? scsi_device_put+0x2f/0x40
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff811d66bc>] ? block_ioctl+0x3c/0x40
 [<ffffffff811af522>] ? vfs_ioctl+0x22/0xa0
 [<ffffffff811af6c4>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x84/0x580
 [<ffffffff8123aa06>] ? security_file_permission+0x16/0x20
 [<ffffffff8119a365>] vfs_read+0xb5/0x1a0
 [<ffffffff8119b116>] ? fget_light_pos+0x16/0x50
 [<ffffffff8119a6b1>] sys_read+0x51/0xb0
 [<ffffffff8100b0d2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
INFO: task mdadm:2357 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Not tainted 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
mdadm         D 0000000000000002     0  2357   2179 0x00000004
 ffff880821773688 0000000000000082 0000000000000000 0000000000000086
 ffff880821773618 ffffffff810633a3 0000013e9de36948 ffff88081f96d440
 ffff88081dc65ed0 000000010010516a ffff88081d713068 ffff880821773fd8
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff810633a3>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
 [<ffffffffa0240805>] get_active_stripe+0x2d5/0x880 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff81130d00>] ? mempool_alloc+0x20/0x140
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff810a6bce>] ? prepare_to_wait+0x4e/0x80
 [<ffffffffa02455ef>] make_request+0x19f/0xcb0 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff812ab7de>] ? __sg_alloc_table+0x7e/0x130
 [<ffffffff81056cc5>] ? gup_pte_range+0xe5/0x130
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff8143066f>] md_make_request+0xdf/0x240
 [<ffffffff8127ddb0>] generic_make_request+0x240/0x5a0
 [<ffffffff811d941c>] ? do_direct_IO+0x57c/0xfa0
 [<ffffffff811d60cb>] ? bio_alloc_bioset+0x5b/0xf0
 [<ffffffff8127e180>] submit_bio+0x70/0x120
 [<ffffffff811daabd>] __blockdev_direct_IO_newtrunc+0xc7d/0x1270
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff811db127>] __blockdev_direct_IO+0x77/0xe0
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff811d73a7>] blkdev_direct_IO+0x57/0x60
 [<ffffffff811d6320>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff8113028b>] generic_file_aio_read+0x6bb/0x700
 [<ffffffff8143877f>] ? md_ioctl+0x31f/0x1ac0
 [<ffffffff811d7f00>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
 [<ffffffff81196d47>] ? __dentry_open+0x257/0x380
 [<ffffffff811d6891>] blkdev_aio_read+0x51/0x80
 [<ffffffff81199a6a>] do_sync_read+0xfa/0x140
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff811d66bc>] ? block_ioctl+0x3c/0x40
 [<ffffffff811af522>] ? vfs_ioctl+0x22/0xa0
 [<ffffffff811af6c4>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x84/0x580
 [<ffffffff8123aa06>] ? security_file_permission+0x16/0x20
 [<ffffffff8119a365>] vfs_read+0xb5/0x1a0
 [<ffffffff8119b116>] ? fget_light_pos+0x16/0x50
 [<ffffffff8119a6b1>] sys_read+0x51/0xb0
 [<ffffffff8100b0d2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
INFO: task md128_reshape:2428 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Not tainted 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
md128_reshape D 0000000000000001     0  2428      2 0x00000000
 ffff88081fdcfa60 0000000000000046 0000000000000000 0000000000000086
 ffff88081fdcf9f0 ffffffff810633a3 0000013d983220e0 ffff88081f96d440
 ffff88081dc65ed0 0000000100103f9f ffff88081ea1e5f8 ffff88081fdcffd8
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff810633a3>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
 [<ffffffffa0240805>] get_active_stripe+0x2d5/0x880 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffffa02447c0>] reshape_request+0x440/0xa20 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff810633a3>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
 [<ffffffffa02450b2>] sync_request+0x312/0x3a0 [raid456]
 [<ffffffff81430ff7>] md_do_sync+0x6c7/0xd60
 [<ffffffff81431ae5>] md_thread+0x115/0x150
 [<ffffffff810a68a0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<ffffffff814319d0>] ? md_thread+0x0/0x150
 [<ffffffff810a640e>] kthread+0x9e/0xc0
 [<ffffffff8100c28a>] child_rip+0xa/0x20
 [<ffffffff810a6370>] ? kthread+0x0/0xc0
 [<ffffffff8100c280>] ? child_rip+0x0/0x20
```

Now, commands like pvscan and other commands that control the md array hang.  Essentially the only thing I can do is reboot to get back to a state where I can control the array.  Even the reboot hangs toward the end, at which point I have to hard reset.

Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?   I did try booting to an ubunutu live cd, but when I wanted to assemble the array, the entire thing froze.

Comment: I bit the bullet and recreated the array with the missing devices and readded them.  I'm not sure if this is going to work, since it was in the middle of a reshape...but it's recovering now.

Comment: md126 : active raid6 sdl[15] sdn[14] sde[13] sdd[12] sdb[11] sdc[10] sdm[7] sdo[6] sdk[5] sdj[4] sdi[3] sdh[2] sdg[1] sdf[0]
      46882646016 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [14/12] [UUUUUUUU__UUUU]
      [>....................]  recovery =  0.0% (3446904/3906887168) finish=4980.7min speed=13061K/sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end, I was able to recover this array by doing the following command:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md126 --level=6 --raid-devices=14 --name=gigantor:128 /dev/sdf /dev/sdg /dev/sdh /dev/sdi /dev/sdj /dev/sdk /dev/sdo /dev/sdm missing missing /dev/sdc /dev/sdb /dev/sdd /dev/sde --assume-clean
```

Then adding the two devices back in.

```
mdadm --add /dev/md126 /dev/sdn
mdadm --add /dev/md126 /dev/sdl
```

Afterwards, since my LVM info was also corrupted, I had to recover that:

```
pvcreate --uuid "kvEA4X-vobg-2Ipz-ITF1-ZhtW-Ewej-6liKVx" --restorefile /etc/lvm/backup/vg_data /dev/md126
vgcfgrestore vg_data
lvchange -ay /dev/vg_data/lvm0
```

Then I tried to xfs_check the LVM, and it said I needed to run repair and destroy the logs:

```
xfs_repair -L /dev/mapper/vg_data-lvm0
```

After this repaired, I could now mount my LVM and my data was intact.

My LVM is repairing.

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md126 : active raid6 sdm[14] sdl[7] sdk[15] sdn[6] sdj[5] sdi[4] sdg[2] sde[0] sdf[1] sdh[3] sdc[12] sda[11] sdd[13] sdb[10]
      46882646016 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [14/12] [UUUUUUUU__UUUU]
      [==========>..........]  recovery = 53.6% (2097061864/3906887168) finish=2448.0min speed=12321K/sec
      bitmap: 0/30 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : active raid6 sdac[15] sdaa[13] sdz[2] sdab[0] sdq[9] sdy[14] sdx[4] sdr[8] sdp[10] sdo[16] sdv[6] sdu[7] sdw[5] sds[12] sdt[11]
      50789533184 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [15/15] [UUUUUUUUUUUUUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

What a pain....